# HTML file input causes destory of parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

Assuming a simple angular component like this:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.scss']
})
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() testo?: string;

  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  inputChange(event: any) {
   this.valueChange.emit(event);
  }

  ngOnChanges(event: any): void{
    console.log(event);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(event: any): void {
      console.log(event);
      console.log("Destroy");
  }
}
```

And the html like this:

```
<input #fileInput
       id="importFile"
       type="file"
       style="display: none"
       (change)="inputChange($event)" />

<button type="button"
        mat-raised-button
        color="accent"
        (click)="fileInput.click()">
    {{this.testo}}
</button>
```

If A file is selected and confirmed in the file explorer everything works fine,
but if the input window is closed or canceled there's a small freeze of chrome/mozilla and then the whole component is destroyed (from logging).

If the component is in a popup (a component opened as popup), all the component is destroyed (and the popup is closed). That's the major issue.

As I remenber, that code worked correctly some times ago,
Also other apps that uses input file have the "small freeze" issue (also some found on stackblitz)

Thanks

Comment: where is (valueChange) used?  Sounds like cancel event from browser is causing an issue... maybe include parent markup and method tied to (valueChange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the input file fires a cancel event.

There was no trace of that on childrens but it fires my "cancel()"

I switched (roughly) the cancel code from:

```
  cancel(event:any) {
          this.dialogRef.close({type: CallbackDetailsState.CANCEL} as DetailsCallback );
  }
```

to

```
  cancel(event:any) {
      if (event && event.target && event.target.toString() == "[object HTMLInputElement]") {
          console.log("Prevent Close");
      } else {
          this.richiesta.note = '';
          this.dialogRef.close({type: CallbackDetailsState.CANCEL} as DetailsCallback );
      }
  }
```

where cancel is triggered as an action from a form app, ie:

```
(updateForm)="updateForm($event)"
(saveForm)="saveOgg($event)"
(cancel)="cancel($event)">
```

the - unattended - generated event is:

```
Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'cancel', target: input#importFile, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: 0, …}
isTrusted: true
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
returnValue: true
srcElement: input#importFile
target: input#importFile
timeStamp: 7451.100000143051
type: "cancel"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove ngOnDestroy with Parameters.

The ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook should not have any parameters. Change the signature of your ngOnDestroy method to:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("Destroy");
}
```

If you need to perform cleanup operations before the component is destroyed, you can do so within this method.

If you're opening the component as a popup, make sure that the popup is being managed correctly. If the popup is being closed when the file input is canceled, ensure that you're handling the closure of the popup in a way that doesn't destroy the component unexpectedly.

Comment: The ngOnDestroy was added to try to check what happens, also without the ngOnDestroy at all the issues remains. If there's a component, with input, called via routes only the "temporary freeze" happen, if the component is loaded in popup the whole popup will close. As I've found there's no way to catch the input file cancel. I've tried to follow all the lifecycle of the popup but the issues seems to pass only on the ngOnDestroy of the hierarchy. Nothing on onChange, callbacks, event emitter, etc

Comment: Oh okay I see. Have you tried to manually check change? I wonder if manually checking inputChange will find the reason this is happening. Based on the code you provided, I cannot see where it is happening.

Comment: Nothing, inputChange is never triggered on cancel, only on submit file (where the event is the file). Can't find a point where to catch it before onDestroy. I've also tested this exact code (https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-file-upload/), in the popup makes the same.